# Auto-update device running linux via cronjob/crontab and git?

Tags: git, git-bash, auto-update

I have a device running linux (a raspberry pi to be precise, but I think that does not really matter) and it is connected to the internet via a router with dhcp (so no fixed IP-Adress), so I cannot access it via SSH.
I have a python application/script running on that device, which I sometimes need to update. I dont want to bother the admin to do something manually, nor do I want to go that place in person to update the code.

I therefore thought of the following solution:

1. Run a bash-script every hour (via a cronjob)
2. Script runs in the directory of the python application "git pull origin" so that, if I updated the master branch of my respository it will receive the update
3. Furthermore I would run a something like an "after-update"-bash script after "git pull" finished if I need to change something else on the device...

Is that a feasible solution or is there some risk and/or far better solution I dont see right now?

Comment: If you are listening to HTTP anyway, why not add a password-protected route where you can make the script update itself and restart?

Comment: @triplee thanks for the comment. What do you mean by "password-protected route"?

Comment: Make it require a password or somehow otherwise a secret so that not anybody who knows the route can mess with your system.

Comment: @triplee I dont understand what you mean. Only a person who has access to my git repository could mess with my system, since only from there sources are taken. The repository is password protected...

Comment: But if you can restart the system just by connecting to https://example.net/git-update-thyself they could DoS your system by visiting that URL once per second. Require a password to actually reboot and they can visit all they want as long as they can't guess the password.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding and my obviously bad explanation. The device does not host a website or anything, it is only connected to the internet, but there is no special port-forwarding to it or anything, connecting to it via ssh is not possible...